# Search with a list of terms in a dataframe column where rows are lists of eligible terms

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter a dataframe by using a list of search terms. I need to check if any of the terms in the list `filter_by` are present in one of the rows of my dataframe. Each row in the dataframe contains a list of eligible terms.

I tried several hacks and more verbose solutions that kind of work. **I wonder if there is a simple and possibly vectorized solutions to this.**

Example list of search terms:

```
filter_by = ["CSV", "JPG", "TXT"]
```

Example dataframe:

```
    data
0   [JPG, XML, PDF, TXT, XLS, XLSX]
1   [XLS, JPG, PDF, XLSX]
2   [JPG, PDF, TXT]
3   [XLS, PDF, XML, JPG]
4   [CSV]
5   [PDF, TXT, XLS]
6   [XML]
7   [JPG]
8   [PDF, CSV, XML, XLS, TXT, JPG]
9   [TXT, CSV, XLS, XLSX, PDF, JPG]
```

The resulting dataframe should only contain the rows where one or more of the elements of `filter_by` is present (`OR` condition).

I tried:

- Flattening each dataframe row to a string and using `str.contains("|".join(filter_by)`. This works. But it seems strange to me that I have to change the data structure fundamentally to achieve such a seemingly simple task.
- `.apply()` and a custom function. This works but seems verbose.
- `.query()` doesn't seem to be a solution. Neither is something like `df[df.data.isin(filter_by)]`.
- I also searched for similar questions on SO, to no avail.

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if there is a simpler way than `apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `not set(filter_by).isdisjoint` inside `apply`:

```
filter_by = ["CSV", "JPG", "TXT"]
df[~df.data.apply(set(filter_by).isdisjoint)]
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `explode()`

```
df['data'].explode().isin(filter_by).groupby(level=0).any()
```